# Javax Swing change menu background color while app is running

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, colors

I have a Javax Swing application that I want to change the background color of the menu while the application is running. I can easily change the color on startup using the nimbus theme and setting the nimbusBase property. This also works to change other colors in the app while it's running but not the menu:

```
UIManager.put("nimbusBase", LIGHT_NIMBUS_BASE_COLOR);
```

I am able to change other colors while the application is running using a similar line but for some reason the menu will not update it's color. After all colors are updated I call:

```
frame.repaint();
```

Comment: How do you apply the color to the menu?

Comment: Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Changing the LAF After Startup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#dynamic)

Comment: Thanks, turns out the frame I was trying to repaint didn't have all of the necessary components attached to it. So with some digging and checking out the LAF page again I was able to get all of the components updated, the menu included.